# Express cannot read property

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

My Controller:

```
exports.showit = function(req, res){
 res.render('showpost', {
  title: req.post.title,
  post: req.post
 })
}
```

My post model includes title and name objects:

```
title: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
name: {type : String, default : '', trim : true},
....and so on.
```

And in ejs, I am trying to reach post title via the following :

```
<h3><%= article.title %></h3>
```

And I am getting an error : "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

I could not figure it out what is my problem though, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing an `article` variable to the template, just `title` and `post`. So use this:

```
<%= title %>
// or
<%= post.title %>
```

Comment: btw, if you dont mind , could you pls check it out this question as well [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411697/post-json-data-in-order-to-render-page].  Although they look like similar, I think I am doing somethng wrong in Post and Get methods.