# Post JSON data to render page

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, get

I am getting my search result as JSON format from the URL: "/accounts/:id/users" and I need to retrieve that JSON data to render "/contacts/find". (The latter page shows search results.)

Here is my app router. With this I could see the result of the search in /contacts/find in JSON format:

```
app.post('/contacts/find', function(req, res) {
  var searchStr = req.param('searchStr', null);
  if ( null == searchStr ) {
    res.send(400);
    return;
  }

  models.Account.findByString(searchStr, function onSearchDone(err,accounts) {
    if (err || accounts.length == 0) {
      res.send(404);
    } else {
      res.send(accounts);
    }
  });
});
```

How can I use "accounts" (in JSON format) and re-render the page with the account info? I am trying with the below code snippet, but it does not work.

```
app.get('/contacts/find', function(req, res) {
 res.render('searchResult.ejs', {
  accounts: req.accounts,
  email: req.accounts.email
 })
}
```

The app.get method is not working.  The URL just shows JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `accounts` is a JSON string? In that case, you can parse it (to convert it back to an object) and pass the result to your template:

```
var accounts = JSON.parse(req.accounts);
res.render('searchResult.ejs', {
  accounts : accounts,
  email    : accounts.email
 })
```

Comment: Is it ok if I render the page within the "app.post" method without using "app.get" method ?

Comment: @eknbrk sure, I don't see why not. Just replace the `res.send` in your POST route with the `res.render`

Comment: thanks again @robertklep.. It worked but, it page renders <%email%> as "undefined".. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @eknbrk well sounds like `accounts.email` might be undefined?